# Refactoring unnested conditional statements

Tags: java, refactoring, conditional-statements, statements

I have a composite component that calls my backing bean. Here I pass the parameters of some image:

```
<h:outputText value="#{MyBBean.formRequest(
   cc.attrs.type, 
   cc.attrs.orientation, 
   cc.attrs.title, 
   cc.attrs.width, 
   cc.attrs.height, 
   cc.attrs.xlabel, 
   cc.attrs.ylabel, 
   cc.attrs.value)}" 
escape="false" />
```

Here is the method

```
public boolean formRequest(
      final String type,
      final String orientation,
      final String title,
      final String width,
      final String height,
      final String xlabel,
      final String ylabel) {

   // some actions here

   if (height != null) {
      appendAttribute(HEIGHT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, height, request);
   }

   if (width != null) {
      appendAttribute(WIDTH_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, width, request);
   }

   // the like

   if (ylabel != null ) {
      appendAttribute(Y_LABEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ylabel, request);
   }

   // other actions

   return request.toString();
}
```

And here is the appendAttribute method

```
private void appendAttribute(final String attributeName, 
      final String attributeValue, final StringBuilder builder) {

   builder.append(attributeName);
   builder.append(EQUALS_CHAR);
   builder.append(attributeValue);
   builder.append(AMPERSAND_CHAR);
}
```

Do you have any idea regarding refactoring these unnested if statements? Because, as for me, it smells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could move the if statement into the **appendAttribute** method.  You would then only have the conditional in one place.

```
public boolean formRequest(
  final String type,
  final String orientation,
  final String title,
  final String width,
  final String height,
  final String xlabel,
  final String ylabel) {

  appendAttribute(HEIGHT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, height, request);
  appendAttribute(WIDTH_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, width, request);
  appendAttribute(Y_LABEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ylabel, request);
  return request.toString();
}
```

and:

```
private void appendAttribute(final String attributeName, 
  final String attributeValue, final StringBuilder builder) {

  if(attributeValue != null) {
      builder.append(attributeName);
      builder.append(EQUALS_CHAR);
      builder.append(attributeValue);
      builder.append(AMPERSAND_CHAR);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 I would just suggest then renaming the method to `appendNonNullAttribute`

Comment: But, anyway, do you think it's considered ok, to leave it in this condition, without using any polimorphism and the like?